# How to change state in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change the state, but it is not working.

This is my state in App.js:

```
class App extends React.Component {    
state = {
    one: [
      {
    id: 1,
    sum: "400",
      }
    ],
    two: {
      title: "test",
      number: "0",
    }
  };
```

And here is my function:

```
Change = (value) => {
    this.setState({ number: "300" });
```

But the number does not change. 
I have also tried:

```
Change = (value) => {
    this.setState({ two.number: "300" });
```

But this is not working either. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: You should not have nested objects in the state, react won't rerender.

Comment: `two.number` won't work. First one could work, but I don't see any code invoking it

Comment: Actually first one won't work either. There is no `number`. There is only `one` and `two`

Answer (score 3):

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ 
  two: { 
    ...prevState.two, 
    number: "300" 
  } 
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this.

```
var two = { ...this.state.two }
two.number = "300";
this.setState({two})
```

Craete a dummy object to handle your state object, and then you set it into the state using the **setState**

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly accessing the nested property. This has been answered here

[How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)